# Матрица поворота

Tags: css, html5, математика, css-animation, геометрия

Есть плоскость Р1 на вращающейся в 3D плоскости Р2. Изначально углы поворота Р2: x2=0, y2=0, z2=0 и обе плоскости отображаются лицом к наблюдателю. Если не менять угол поворота у Р1, то она вращается вместе с Р2.
Как вычислять углы поворота x1, y1, z1 для Р1 чтобы она была как в начальный момент времени (всегда лицом к наблюдателю).

```js
<script>
            var p2 = document.querySelector('i');
            var p1 = document.querySelector('u');
            
            var x2=0, y2=0, z2=0; // значения угла поворота p2 или элемент i
            
            var x1 = Math.cos(x0); // нужна правильная формула
            var y1 = Math.cos(y0); // нужна правильная формула
            var z1 = Math.cos(z0); // нужна правильная формула
            
            p2.style.transform = 'rotateX('+x0+'deg) rotateY('+y0+'deg) rotateZ('+z0+'deg)';
            p1.style.transform = 'rotateX('+x1+'deg) rotateY('+y1+'deg) rotateZ('+z1+'deg)';
        </script>
```

```css
body, i{
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
            }
            i {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                display: block;
                background: #0f0;
                position:absolute;
            }
            u {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                display: block;
                background: #00f;
                position:absolute;
                transform-origin: bottom center;
            }
```

```html
<i><u></u></i>
```

На примере, я вращаю зеленый блок (плоскость), а синяя должна быть повернута так, что визуально всегда остаётся "неподвижной" к наблюдателю.

Comment: *Есть плоскость Р1 на вращающейся в 3D плоскости Р2.* - что значит есть плоскость на плоскости?

Comment: Угол z (между плоскостью P1 и осью, перпендикулярной плоскости проецирования, то есть экрану) всегда 90 град. Остальные как пожелаете - можете синхронизировать с соответствующими углами плоскости P2.

Comment: То есть, угол между нормалью к плоскости Р1 и плоскостью проектирования 0 гр.  или 180 в зависимости от направления нормали

Comment: Если смотреть все точки плоскости, то точки плоскости P1 будут лежать на P2 в начальный момент (0,0,0). Нормали в этот момент совпадают

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось всё намного проще: нужно было выполнить поворот с отрицательными значениями родительского объекта и в обратном порядке:

```
var x1 = -x2;
var y1 = -y2;
var z1 = -z2;
p2.style.transform = 'rotateX('+x2+'deg) rotateY('+y2+'deg) rotateZ('+z2+'deg)';
p1.style.transform = 'rotateZ('+z1+'deg) rotateY('+y1+'deg) rotateX('+x1+'deg)';
```

[решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701062/13779527)